# Iterate through a list in C# MVC and access properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a view that accepts a ProjectsCreatorsVM class. This class has been structured this way:

```
public class ProjectsCreatorsVM
{
    public List<ProjectVM> ProjectsCreators { get; set; }
    public ProjectsCreatorsVM(List<ProjectVM> projectsCreators)
    {
        ProjectsCreators = projectsCreators;
    }
}
```

In addition, the ProjectVM follow this structure:

```
public class ProjectVM
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public  ProjectVM(Project pro, ApplicationUser applUser)
    {
        Project = pro;
        ApplicationUser = applUser;
    }
}
```

Lastly, my view tries to go through the ProjectsCreators.Project but it does not seem to be possible.

```
<div class="card-content-container" >
        @foreach (Project obj in @Model.ProjectsCreators.)
        {
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="@obj.ImgURL"  alt ="project image" >
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@obj.Title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-title">@obj.Title</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        @obj.TruncatedDescription
                    </p>
                    <div class="mt-auto" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                        <a href="/Customer/ProjectVisitor/ViewProjectDetail?id=@obj.Id" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Project obj in @Model.ProjectsCreators.` -- uh, sure its `Project` not `ProjectVM`? also, what that trailing dot do? any error message you get?

Comment: I think you may want to select the `Project` property for each `ProjectCreators` object: `@Model.ProjectsCreators.Select(pc => pc.Project)`.

Comment: The trailing says: List<ProjectVM> does not contain a definition for 'Project'.

I have been looking at this line:
@model HelloUniverse.Models.ViewModels.ProjectsCreatorsVM

this is the import I am using in my view. But I think it makes sense to import that. Since I am using the ProjectsCreatorsVM class in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ProjectCreators** is a **List** and when you iterate **ProjectCreators** you get a **ProjectVM** object not a **Project** or **ApplicaionUser** instance. If you want to access **Project** instance add **Project** after **@obj** like **@obj.Project.Title**

```
<div class="card-content-container" >
    @foreach (ProjectVM obj in @Model.ProjectsCreators.)
    {
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="@obj.Project.ImgURL"  alt ="project image" >
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <h5 class="card-title">@obj.Project.Title</h5>
                <h6 class="card-title">@obj.Project.Title</h6>
                <p class="card-text">
                        @obj.Project.TruncatedDescription
                </p>
                <div class="mt-auto" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                    <a href="/Customer/ProjectVisitor/ViewProjectDetail?id=@obj.Project.Id" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Baris.

I have changed my foreach. However, I now get the following: The type or namespace name 'ProjectVM' could not be found. 

If I change my @model  ProjectVM instead of ProjectsCreatorVM. I won;t be able to use ProjectsCreatorsVM.

model HelloUniverse.Models.ViewModels.ProjectsCreatorsVM
            foreach (ProjectVM obj in @Model.ProjectsCreators)
            {
                
            }

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what I wanted, I created another class. That looks like this:

```
 public class ProjectAndUserVM
{
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCreatorName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCreatorId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCreatorEmail { get; set; }
    public ProjectAndUserVM(string projectTitle, string projectId, string projectImageUrl, string projectDescription, string projectCreatorName, string projectCreatorId, string projectCreatorEmail)
    {
        ProjectTitle = projectTitle;
        ProjectId = projectId;
        ProjectImageUrl = projectImageUrl;
        ProjectDescription = projectDescription;
        ProjectCreatorName = projectCreatorName;
        ProjectCreatorId = projectCreatorId;
        ProjectCreatorEmail = projectCreatorEmail;
    }
}
```

So, basically my controller is returning that as a list which I convert to an IEnumerable. and I use that list on my view instead.